# Django easy friends: tuple indices must be integers, not unicode

Tags: python, django, facebook

I am using [**django-easy-friends**](https://github.com/barszczmm/django-easy-friends#friendscontribsuggestions-application) to import contacts from facebook.

But when I click on the link facebook on 'import contacts' page I am getting the following. Please help on this. Thanks.

```
[17/Jul/2013 00:06:50] "GET /friends/suggestions/import_facebook_contacts/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Internal Server Error: /oauth/login/facebook/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/src/django-oauth-access/oauth_access/views.py", line 11, in oauth_login
    access = OAuthAccess(service)
  File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/src/django-oauth-access/oauth_access/access.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.consumer = oauth.Consumer(self.key, self.secret)
  File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/src/django-oauth-access/oauth_access/access.py", line 44, in key
    return self._obtain_setting("keys", "KEY")
  File "/home/deep/.virtualenvs/django_project/src/django-oauth-access/oauth_access/access.py", line 70, in _obtain_setting
    return getattr(settings, name)[service][k1][k2]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not unicode
[17/Jul/2013 00:06:50] "GET /oauth/login/facebook/?next=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Ffriends%2Fsuggestions%2Fimport_facebook_contacts%2F HTTP/1.1" 500 75884
```